# Concatenation with empty string raises ERR:INVALID DIM

Tags: string, string-concatenation, ti-basic

In TI-BASIC, the `+` operation is overloaded for string concatenation (in this, if nothing else, TI-BASIC joins the rest of the world).

However, any attempt to concatenate involving an empty string raises a Dimension Mismatch error:

```
"Fizz"+"Buzz"
        FizzBuzz 
"Fizz"+""
           Error
""+"Buzz"
           Error
""+""
           Error
```

Why does this occur, and is there an elegant workaround? I've been using a starting space and truncating the string when necessary (doesn't always work well) or using a loop to add characters one at a time (slow).

Comment: why would you need to concatenate an empty string? Just curious

Comment: @Meepo For example, when writing the FizzBuzz program, I may want to keep a string each iteration and append "Fizz" if the current number is divisible by 3 and "Buzz" if by 5. This covers three of the four cases. Also, I may want to use an unknown string in a program—what if it's empty?

Comment: I think ti-basic deals with empty strings in a weird way (probably to save memory), so if you post some more code I would be happy to help you find a way around this

Answer (score 2):

The best way depends on what you are doing.

If you have a string (in this case, Str1) that you need to concatenate with another (Str2), and you don't know if it is empty, then this is a good general-case solution:

```
Str2
If length(Str1
Str1+Str2
```

If you need to loop and add a stuff to the string each time, then this is your best solution:

Before the loop:

```
" →Str1
```

In the loop:

```
Str1+<stuff_that_isn't_an_empty_string>→Str1
```

After the loop:

```
sub(Str1,2,length(Str1)-1→Str1
```

There are other situations, too, and if you have a specific situation, then you should post a simplified version of the relevant code.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

It is very unfortunate that TI-Basic doesn't support empty strings. If you are starting with an empty string and adding chars, you have to do something like this:

```
"?
For(I,1,3
Prompt Str1
Ans+Str1
End
sub(Ans,2,length(Ans)-1
```

Another useful trick is that if you have a string that you are eventually going to evaluate using `expr(`, you can do `"("+Str1+")"→Str1` and then freely do search and replace on the string. This is a necessary workaround since you can't search and replace any text involving the first or last character in a string.